TeXbook Exercise 21.10 Answer
I have read
Question about exercise 21.10 in The TeXbook
and:
https://tug.org/mail-archives/tex-k/2019-November/003087.html
but did not find what I was looking for.
Same for searching the web. Nothing. Zip.
Can anyone explain the answer provided for Exercise 21.20. It is about expanding chapter numbers immediately and page numbers at shipout.
The answer is:

{\let\the=0\edef\next{\write\cont{⟨token list⟩}}\next} will expand everything but \the when the \write command is given.

What does \the have to do with expanding page numbers at shipout?
What is \cont?
What tokens might go into the token list?
Thanks for any help.
VH

Welcome to TeX-sx! The link you've posted shows the definition for \cont, so I am wondering how much detail you've looked at already.

I somewhat understand  \write, but am asking basic questions. So yes, I read the other post, but still did not understand everything. So I ask what I call "dumb questions"—my term—questions with obvious answers for experts, which I am not. To make the reasons for this more clear, as a journalist, I have been very successfully at researching and writing technical topics for more than 40 years because I ask "dumb questions"—again, my term. I have used LaTeX for more than 20 years—mostly article class. These days I am learning TeX and Plain TeX and working at understanding macros. Thanks.

I think this question is probably just a duplicate of the referenced one (which naturally has a very informative answer:-) but I'll try to answer again here.

What does \the have to do with expanding page numbers at shipout?

The page number is stored in the count register \count0 so one way of getting the value of the count is \the\count0 which expands to its current value.
In fact this TeXBook suggestion is not that great and by default plain TeX uses \number and \rommannumeral rather than \the in its page number macro.
However the question explicitly asks about the simplified case just needing \the so the answer is correct for the question as asked.
Plain TeX uses
\def\folio{\ifnum\pageno<\z@ \romannumeral-\pageno \else\number\pageno \fi}

so a more practical suggestion than suppressing \the would be to suppress all three of \the, \number and \romannumeral or, to be specific to page numbers, suppress the expansion of \folio. The LaTeX version in the answer of the linked question takes this last option, suppressing the expansion of \thepage which is the LaTeX equivalent of \folio.

What is \cont?

This is a command defined in the answer that you link to
\newwrite\cont \openout\cont=out.txt

so it's a write stream (being a sketch of a table of contents file, like a latex .toc) which collects the chapter titles and page numbers.

What tokens might go into the token list?

Anything. This is clearly modelling a table of contents, so any tokens used in a chapter title.
if you are on page 10 but as part of chapter processing the next chapter will be on a new odd page, page 11
\def\chapno{5}
\immediate\write\cont{\chapno???\the\count0}

Then 5???10 would be written to the file. If you delay the write with
\def\chapno{5}
\write\cont{\chapno???\the\count0}

then \chapno???\the\count0 will be expanded at shipout time so \the\count0 will expand to 11 as required but \chapno may have gone out of scope and error, or may already be referencing the next chapter. So the solution is
\def\chapno{5}
{%
\let\the=0 % or \relax or anything that doesn't expand
\edef\tmp{\write\cont{\chapno???\the\count0}}%

% at this point \tmp is \write\cont{5???\the\count0} as \the did not expand.
\tmp
}

% this now executes the \write so as the next page is shipped out 5 will get written as 5 and \the will by then have its usual definition so \the\count0 will expand to the page number of the page being shipped out.

Thanks for your answer. My question was a bit redundant, I admit, but I did not fully understand your other answer. Donald Knuth sometimes seems to intentionally supply answers meant more to stretch than directly answer. Maybe Answer 21.10 was one of these. But your answers to both questions have helped me understand, I think. Delayed expansion is simple in concept but difficult for me to implement.  I do recognize you because of your longterm deep and wide contributions to the world of TeX and friends. Thanks for taking your time to reply.


Exercise 21.10
Suppose that you want to \write a token list that
involves a macro \chapno, containing the current chapter number, as well as
‘\the\count0’ which refers to the current page. You want \chapno to
be expanded immediately, because it might change before the token list
is written; but you want \the\count0 to be expanded at the time of
\shipout. How can you manage this?


21.10. If you say ‘{\let\the=0\edef\next{\write\cont{<token list>}}\next}’,
the \write will be executed after \edef expands everything except \the.

According to the text of the exercise, \chapno will expand to ‘21’ if the current chapter is 21. Let's say that the <token list> is
Chapter \chapno, page \the\count0

What's \cont? It's simply the name of an open output stream, according to the syntax of \write, so you can assume that \newwrite\cont and \openout\cont<filename> have been issued.
The outer braces in
{\let\the=0\edef\next{\write\cont{Chapter \chapno, page \the\count0}}\next}

are very important, because they delimit the scope of \let\the=0, so \the will return to its previous meaning when the closing } is processed.
What happens when \edef is executed? The tokens \write and \cont are unexpandable, so \edef does nothing to them; then Chapter and the space are untouched, but \chapno is fully expanded; comma, page and space remain the same. Now the main point: \the has been made the same as 0, so in this scope it is unexpandable, so \edef doesn't touch it. Since \count is unexpandable, what you get is the same as
\def\next{\write\cont{Chapter 21, page \the\count0}}

and therefore, upon expansion of \next, you get
\write\cont{Chapter 21, page \the\count0}

The token list given as argument to \write sits there waiting for the next shipout, when it will be fully expanded; now \the has its primitive meaning and therefore the page number current when \shipout is performed is eventually written out.
LaTeX employs a similar trick, because it uses \protected@write:
% latex.ltx, line 9050:
\long\def \protected@write#1#2#3{%
      \begingroup
       \let\thepage\relax
       #2%
       \let\protect\@unexpandable@protect
       \edef\reserved@a{\write#1{#3}}%
       \reserved@a
      \endgroup
      \if@nobreak\ifvmode\nobreak\fi\fi
}

Instead of braces, \begingroup and \endgroup are used and instead of \let\the=0 LaTeX has \let\thepage\relax which amounts to essentially the same thing, because \relax is unexpandable.

Thank you! This is helpful.
